# Can video be scaled to fit a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, media-player, glsurfaceview

The following is is the layout used by [MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) except that I changed the dimensions to a weird resolution (300x480) to just make the point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="480dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</SurfaceView>
```

Yes, the video is displayed exactly in a window of 300 x 480, but the video is scaled to fit the width of my tablet (1024), and the window shows a part (300 x 480) of the entire video (1024 x 680).
I thought, from my reading, the video would scale to fit the size of the SurfaceView.

Is there a way to scale the video to fit a SurfaceView?

Comment: Which video format do you use? I've tested both 3gp and mp4 on 3.2 emulator, video is scaled and played entirely in 300 x 480 area.

Comment: I use RTSP.  Thanks a lot for testing. Let me try the same, and will report back.

Comment: Sorry, but I missed mentioning that H.264 is the format.

Comment: I played a 3gp on my generic tablet, the problem remains.  Unfortunately I am having a difficulty running it on emulators.  I keep getting "error: Prepare failed" when playing the stream: rtsp://v2.cache8.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwk4RDShYkdS1BMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNg3bauluLF27tPDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp

Comment: I also tried a local mp4 file on an SD card.  The issue remains with my tablet.  I still cannot get emulators to play video. I keep getting MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) when using an emulator regardless of whether it is an RTSP stream or a local file.